# XML input into a temp table

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I am new to using XML within SQL server and am struggling a little to get what I need. I have tried working a few examples from around the site into what I need but no luck, any help would be appreciated my raw XML is as follows

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Service xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <mParentServiceServiceID>37694</mServiceID>
      <mJourneyMessage>Cancelled</mJourneyMessage>
      <mApplicableDate>2014-10-10</mApplicableDate>
      <Edits>
        <mServiceID>14466</mServiceID>
        <mStopSequenceOrdinal>2</mStopSequenceOrdinal>
      </Edits>
      <Edits>
        <mServiceID>14466</mServiceID>
        <mStopSequenceOrdinal>3</mStopSequenceOrdinal>
      </Edits>
      <Edits>
        <mServiceID>14467</mServiceID>
        <mStopSequenceOrdinal>5</mStopSequenceOrdinal>
      </Edits>
      <Edits>
        <mServiceID>14467</mServiceID>
        <mStopSequenceOrdinal>4</mStopSequenceOrdinal>
      </Edits>
      <Edits>
        <mServiceID>14468</mServiceID>
        <mStopSequenceOrdinal>4</mStopSequenceOrdinal>
      </Edits>
    </mEdits>
  </Service>
```

Which is being passed into a stored procedure through an XML variable called @Details

I would like my table to look like the following

```
mParentServiceID|mJourneyMessage|mApplicableDate|mServiceID|mStopsSequenceOrdinal
37694             Cancelled       2014-10-10      14466        2
37694             Cancelled       2014-10-10      14466        3
37694             Cancelled       2014-10-10      14467        5
37694             Cancelled       2014-10-10      14467        4
37694             Cancelled       2014-10-10      14468        4
```

I know this isn't normalized but this is a staging table so that I can do a little data manipulation before storing in the main tables

So far I have the below

```
INSERT  INTO @ApplicableServices
SELECT  *
FROM    OPENXML (@Details, '/Service/', 2)
WITH    (mParentServiceServiceID int '../@SmParentServiceServiceID',
        mJourneyMessage varchar(30) '../@mJourneyMessage ',
        mApplicableDate Date '../@mApplicableDate',
        mServiceID int '@mServiceID ',
        mStopSequenceOrdinal int '@mStopSequenceOrdinal')
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (by the way, there were a couple of syntax errors in the xml, so I had to make a couple of changes, so I have listed it out in full below):

```
DECLARE @XML XML =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Service xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <mParentServiceServiceID>37694</mParentServiceServiceID>
    <mJourneyMessage>Cancelled</mJourneyMessage>
    <mApplicableDate>2014-10-10</mApplicableDate>
    <Edits>
      <mServiceID>14466</mServiceID>
      <mStopSequenceOrdinal>2</mStopSequenceOrdinal>
    </Edits>
    <Edits>
      <mServiceID>14466</mServiceID>
      <mStopSequenceOrdinal>3</mStopSequenceOrdinal>
    </Edits>
    <Edits>
      <mServiceID>14467</mServiceID>
      <mStopSequenceOrdinal>5</mStopSequenceOrdinal>
    </Edits>
    <Edits>
      <mServiceID>14467</mServiceID>
      <mStopSequenceOrdinal>4</mStopSequenceOrdinal>
    </Edits>
    <Edits>
      <mServiceID>14468</mServiceID>
      <mStopSequenceOrdinal>4</mStopSequenceOrdinal>
    </Edits>
  </Service>'

SELECT
     Serv.Edit.value('../mParentServiceServiceID[1]','INT') mParentServiceServiceID
    ,Serv.Edit.value('../mJourneyMessage[1]','VARCHAR(50)') mJourneyMessage
    ,Serv.Edit.value('../mApplicableDate[1]','DATE')        mApplicableDate
    ,Serv.Edit.value('mServiceID[1]','INT')                 mServiceID
    ,Serv.Edit.value('mStopSequenceOrdinal[1]','INT')       mStopSequenceOrdinal

FROM
            @XML.nodes ('//Edits')  AS Serv(Edit)
```